# Choose which Exchange contact folder(s) to sync to phone

Tags: contacts, exchange, active-sync, ms-office

On Office 365, my folder structure is this:

My Contacts [container, not a folder itself]
- LinkedIn
- Contacts
- Contacts2
- Skype for Business Contacts
-...

I want only contacts from my "Contacts" folder to sync to my phone, and not from the other folders.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I don't mind installing a sync app, but don't want to install the Outlook app.

I have seen a hacks using Categories to only show selected contacts in the Contacts app on the phone, but this has 2 problems:

1. I would have to add a Category to every new contact I make in my Contacts folder to get it to sync, which is very error-prone.
2. I think it still syncs all of the contacts from every folder, using phone space and sync bandwidth.

Any help is much appreciated.

Versions:

- Android 8.0.0 on Google/LG Nexus 5X
- Stock GMail (NOT the Outlook app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a Shared User account on Office 365 and putting all non-essential contacts in the Contacts folder of that shared user so they don't appear on my account.

I had to then remove my Exchange account from GMail, reboot, and add the Exchange account again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want to install autlook app then I guess you'll have to install syncing app. I can recommend you https://www.akruto.com/ for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks.  I had a look at Akruto but could not find any evidence that it syncs only selected folders, so I don't know if it solves my problem or not